# web2py query display results

Tags: database, data-access-layer, web2py

I am writing a web2py query to run against the database but it won't display the results as i get an error stating Set: No tables selected...

I was wondering if some one can help me out with this?

The table I was to run the query against is:

```
db.define_table('Flight',
    Field('FlightNum', type = 'string', length = 10, notnull = True),
    Field('PlaneID', type = 'string', length = 10, notnull = True),
    Field('DepartureLocation', type = 'string', length = 20, notnull = True),
    Field('ArrivalLocation', type = 'string', length = 20, notnull = True),
    Field('DepartureDate', type='date'),
    Field('ArrivalDate', type='date'),
    Field('DepartureTime', type = 'time'),
    Field('ArrivalTime', type = 'time'))
```

My query is:

```
def displayFlights():
    tuples=db((db.Flight.DepartureLocation is request.vars.DepartureLocation)&
       (db.Flight.ArrivalLocation is request.vars.ArrivalLocation)&
       (db.Flight.DepartureDate is request.vars.DepartureDate)&
       (db.Flight.ArrivalDate is request.vars.DepartureDate)).select()
    return dict(tuples=tuples)
```

Can some one please help me correct this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries must be constructed with `==`, not `is`:

```
db.Flight.DepartureLocation == request.vars.DepartureLocation
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, 
I am trying that right now however with the HTML form i could have radio buttons with the SQL form or the FORM I can't use it, Hence working with HTML form..

Comment: Yes, you can have radio buttons with `FORM` -- see the book section on [widgets](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#Widgets). Also, note that you can construct the form in HTML but still use the `FORM` object on the server to process the submitted values -- see http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07#SQLFORM-in-HTML. Note, if you use `SQLFORM`, you should use the `.validate()` method or `.process(..., dbio=False)` -- otherwise the submitted values will be inserted as a new record in the database.

Comment: It might also help if you read through the first few chapters of the book (especially the chapters on the DAL and Forms).